# how to set a background image inside the UILabel inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

I'm working on a project in swift 3 where I've set a background image inside the UILabel which is inside a UITableViewCell. The image consist of a gradient color that has a fade away effect on its edges. Once I set this in my code for some reason the gradient color seems to appear only on one side of the label(left side). Perhaps its not been adjusted properly to fit in the UILabel.How can I set the image fits to the label size properly, help would much appreciate. My code as bellow.What am I missing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeaturedCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: cell.bounds.height)
        return cell

    case (1...3):

        let text = self.categorySelectionTitles[indexPath.row  - 2]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AudioCell",for: indexPath)
        let labe = cell.viewWithTag(TABLE_CELL_TAGS.headerLabel) as! UILabel
        labe.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "headerBar")!)
         labe.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
        Utils.setTableCellLabelText(cell: cell, labelTag: 501, text: text)
        return cell

}
```

[image]

As per the picture above right side of the gradient is not there.Orginal picture as bellow.

[image]

Comment: If you are using custom tableview cell then you can add a `UIImageView` behind the `UILabel` with equal width and equal height constraint to that label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use autolayout instead of frames like this:

```
labe.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  labe.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor),
  labe.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor),
  labe.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor),
  labe.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor),
])
```

You'll want to try to make sure the constraints are only added once.

Or use masks:

```
labe.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Comment: can u write this in swift 3 sir

Comment: The issue with the code above is my label does not take the whole cell. therefore once i set this it hides the rest and overlapping